# AWS CDK: How to create lambda without code

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm trying to create an infrastructure with AWS CDK. When creating a lambda, it forces me to specify the code that's going in it.

However, that'll be the responsibility of the release pipeline.

Is there a way to create a lambda without specifying the code?

Comment: Just plug some dummy code in, or literally an empty string / file. That will cause the lambda itself to fail if invoked but that would be expected I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  `code` is a required prop in the CDK Lambda [Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.Function.html) construct<sup>*</sup>.  Use the [InlineCode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.InlineCode.html) class as a minimal placeholder:

```js
new lambda.Function(this, "Lambda", {
    code: new lambda.InlineCode(
        "exports.handler = async (event) => console.log(event)"
    ),
    runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
    handler: "index.handler",
});
```

---

* It's also required for the CDK L1 `CfnFunction`.  For what it's worth, Code is also a [required input](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateFunction.html#SSS-CreateFunction-request-Code) in the `CreateFunction` API and SDK commands.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for sharing. But won't this overwrite the deployed function after we run the cdk deploy command next time?

Comment: Yes, of course.  The CDK app (via CloudFormation) is meant to own the Lambda's runtime code and infrastructure code.  It's a CDK [best practice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-code-all).

Comment: May I suggest you open a \*new question\* that addresses your use case?  To add detail to the part you say  _"that'll be the responsibility of the release pipeline"_.  I don't understand the proposed setup.  I'm glad to help, but it's really a separate question.

Comment: I would *not* expect this to change the code during the next CDK deployment because CloudFormation is incapable of fixing drifted resources itself. During a stack update it should not even see that the code of the lambda changed in the meantime. Obviously still a bad idea since you rely on a bad CF behaviour *and* this would break if you were to ever change the dummy code at which point all lambdas would be overwritten.

Comment: @luk2302 Your "won't overwrite" expectation holds only if: (1) OP never modifies the CDK Lambda code and (2) OP never changes the function name (which will cause a replace-redeploy).

Comment: Yes, the comments make sense. I was thinking of deploying the infrastructure and deploying code with different pipelines but I guess a better usage of this AWS CDK would be to have a build pipeline building and the deployment to run this code with a reference to the build artifact as the function. This will get the lambda infrastructure updated (if required) and the correct lambda code deployed. Thanks, both.